# How to show a field as a Link in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.NET MVC and following the instructions on tutorial at ASP.NET website "getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc". I have an Equipment Class

```
public class Equipment
    {
       [Key] public int EquipID { get; set; }
        public string EquipName { get; set; }
        public string EquipDescription { get; set; }
        public string EquipSerialNumber { get; set; }
        public string EquipImage { get; set; }
        public string EquipManufacturor { get; set; }
        public string EquipLocation { get; set; }
        public string EquipCalibrationFreq { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Calibration> Calibrations { get; set; }
    }
```

and each Equipment class has one or more **Calibration** records. Below is my Calibration class.

```
 public class Calibration
    {
      [Key]  public int RecID { get; set; }
       public int EquipID { get; set; }
        public DateTime CalibrationDate { get; set; }
        public decimal? CalibrationCost { get; set; }
        public String CalibratedBy { get; set; }
        public String CalibrationCert { get; set; }
        public DateTime NextCalibrationDue { get; set; }
        public String ResponsibleSection { get; set; }
        public virtual Equipment Equipment { get; set; }
    }
```

Now  on my Index page for Equipment I am showing related Calibration records (Master-Details). Have a look below:
[image]
So in the column [Calibration Certificate] instead path to document, I want to show a Link to document, which shall open the document either in browser or in associated program.

This is the markup for that child calibration records

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.Calibrations)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CalibrationDate)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CalibratedBy)   </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CalibrationCost)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NextCalibrationDue)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CalibrationCert)   </td>
```

}
Please help me how can I make this a Link to document and the LinkTitle should show the documentName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should be using Action method as given below

```
@if (item.Certificate != null)
    {
        <a href = @Url.Action("ViewCertificate", new { fileName = item.Certificate }) > <img src = "@Url.Content("~/Images/attachment.png")"  alt = "attachment" /> </a>  
    }
```

In place of the attachment image you can put some text saying 'view certificate' as well.

Action method to support file view

```
public ActionResult ViewCertificate(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath("~/Certificates/" + fileName));
            return File(fileStream , "application/pdf", fileName);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "Certificate does not found " + fileName);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Its showing this error even the file is there:Certificate does not found c:\users\shani\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\QA\QA\Content\CaliCert\2222013111358-EnrollmentCert.pdf

Comment: with slight modification Its somehow working, instead of automatically opening the program, the file is being downloaded. Thanks

Comment: If there any corrections please edit the answer, this might help some one in need

Answer (score 1):

You can use inside the td:

```
<a href=@(Model.CalibrationCertLink)>Certificate</a>
```

Yust add a CalibrationCertLink property to the Calibration class to return a relative link to your file.

Answer (score 0):

Add an action link with the parameter in the querystring. Or else we may go for  reporting services webservice like suggested here:
 [Reporting Services Web Service from ASP.NET MVC Using WCF](http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2010/02/26/executing-reporting-services-web-service-from-asp-net-mvc-using-wcf-add-service-reference.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should create DisplayTemplates in Shared Views folder and then in there you should create Template for that example CalibrationCert.cshtml and there you should create your display code:

```
@model List<CalibrationCert>
        @foreach (var a in Model)
            {
//Create hear the display HTML
            }
```

and @ line

```
public virtual ICollection<Calibration> Calibrations { get; set; }
```

you shuld change to:

```
[UIHint("CalibrationCert")]
public virtual ICollection<Calibration> Calibrations { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add an anchor tag for doing this:

```
<a href="@(Model.CalibrationCertLink)" target="_blank">View Certificate</a>
```

When you say `target=_blank` it opens in a new window.

Comment: What is the html rendered ?

Comment: <a href="c:\users\shani\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\QA\QA\Content\CaliCert\2222013122036-EnrollmentCert.pdf">View Certificate</a>